# Rails + Masonry + Rails Error to exibe the More

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Good morning to all, so, i have a problems whit the rails and this two plugins, first i dont know how limit the number of #post to exibe in masonry, i dont find this, and other is my integrations whit the Masonry and the infinitescroll dont works, i make this:

```
//= require jquery.masonry.min
//= require jquery.infinitescroll.min



jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var $container = $('#content');
    $container.imagesLoaded(function () {
        $container.masonry({
            itemSelector:'#post',
            isAnimated:true,
            animationOptions:{
                duration:750,
                easing:'linear',
                queue:false
            }
        });
    });

    $container.infinitescroll({
            navSelector  : "#pag-nav",
            // selector for the paged navigation (it will be hidden)
            nextSelector : "#pag-nav a",
            // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
            itemSelector : "#content div#post"
            // selector for all items you'll retrieve


        },
        // trigger Masonry as a callback
        function( newElements ) {
            var $newElems = $( newElements );
            $container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems );
        }
    );

})
```

the Masonry works but the infinite scroll not, i make the link in the page of masonry:

```
  <div id="pag-nav">
    <a href="#">Carregar mais</a>
  </div>
```

and my rails load all posts

@posts = Post.all
i dont know where i limit the posts to exibe and the infinite scroll dont appear anithing, someone can help me please is very important thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you need use pagination. For this purpose you can use [kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari)

Also, you must add on your controller elements per page, for example `20`:

```
@posts = Post.all.page(params[:page]).per(20)
```

I recomend use this gem for masonry:

https://github.com/kristianmandrup/masonry-rails

It is more complete and you can keep your assets ordered.

Regards